# How could i link a css style sheet with its related HTML file in a nodejs application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am currently trying to understand javascript with nodejs. For getting an introduction, I read an example of js page that "stream" my HTML page , but the style linked with the css isn't used.

Here is the js file:

app.js

```
var http = require('http');

var port = 8080;
//import a module for using the function
var dt = require('./module.js');
//import an html file.
var fs=require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        fs.readFile('test.html',function(err,data) {

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
        }).listen(port);
console.log("Serveur tourne sur http://localhost:"+port);
```

In the HTML file, I linked the CSS, as I usually do in an HTML file with the following tag in the header

the tag: 
     `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"`

a)Could somebody explain to me why it doesn't work? 
b)what are the difference between the usage of normal HTML and this usage, when the HTML is used in a js file?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you link a file in your `html`, whether its a `stylesheet` or a `script` file, browser send an http request to the server for that file.

In your case if you check your console, you'd probably be having `404` response code for that style file ,as you are not sending any file from server side against that request.

You'll have to handle that on your server  side code.

Your server code should like

```js
if(req.url === '/home' || req.url === '/'){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'});
    fs.createReadStream('test.html', 'utf8' ).pipe(res)
  }
  else if(req.url === '/style.css' ){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/css'});
    fs.createReadStream('style.css', 'utf8' ).pipe(res)
  }
```

What's happening here is, I am checking for related request and sending the appropriate data. Now, when browser will request for `/style.css`, server will recognize this request and send the file to browser

And if you're a beginner, I'd recommend you to use [express](https://expressjs.com/). It is a nodejs web framework and makes life easy for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be much more understandable. Correct me if I am wrong:
it mean that , if i reference a picture(.jpg) in the css file, i have to use the same kind of action to make it available , isn't it ? ? 

Thank you very much for the framework, i'll have a look as soon as i can!